# Did Einstein say this about education?

Tags: quotes, albert-einstein

I have read the following quote that is attributed to Albert Einstein:

> The aim of education must be the training of independently acting and
>   thinking individuals who, however, see in the service to the community
>   their highest life problem.

This sounds plausible, but there are many quotes that are misattributed to him; so did he actually say this?

Comment: I have answered my own question as we are [allowed to do](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). I had researched this question before asking it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes, he said this.**

This line has been reworded from an address given by Einstein at the *State University of New York at Albany* on the 15th of October 1931, on the occasion of the 300th anniversary of higher education in America.

On page 60 in *Ideas And Opinions* by Albert Einstein from 1954, the address and the quote are printed.

[Here are excerpts](http://www.cse.iitm.ac.in/~kalyantv/pdf/on_edu.pdf) from the speech.